# BEC or CEB NPN Transistor

Tags: transistors, npn, packages, pinout

I am looking for a small, inexpensive NPN transistor, similar to [2N4401](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N4401.pdf) in specs, with a BEC or CEB pinout.

Does anyone know of any?

Comment: What aspects of its spec is most relevant to you and why not use the transistor you have mentioned?

Comment: Allow me to suggest that you go to a website like Farnell or Digikey, then search for NPNs and fill in the parameters that are important to you, sort by price and see if the suggested NPNs are what you need.

Comment: Current capacity, voltage drop and frequency are probably the most important. BEC pinout would make my PCB layout much more straightforward.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Those websites you mention do not provide a filter for lead pinout, and wading through hundreds of datasheets is not much joy. And google did not help me in this case.

Comment: IIRC that pinout was popular on Japanese video and rf transistors,

Comment: Heh ... BC184 and BC184L give you a choice of CBE and ECB but I've never seen CEB...

Comment: I don't think you're gonna find it. The usual Japanese pinout was ECB. US was EBC and European was CBE (reverse US). Bend the leads around and add some insulating tubing..

Comment: I found a RF transistor [MPSH10](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MP/MPSH10.pdf), but unfortunately it handles much less current, while being quite a bit more expensive.

Comment: Collector in the middle is pretty much standard because that's how the silicon inside the package is arranged.

Comment: There used to be an alternate pin out variant sold to save those designers who had screwed up their layout / footprint, but I cannot for the life of me remember which one it was. I do remember desperately wishing Digi-Key let me search / sort by footprint though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's an RF pinout, "TO92-3" eg fairchild KSP10

Comment: I cannot make sense of the Figure 2 in the [datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/KS/KSP10.pdf). It shows Vce(sat) of around 70-80 volts. ??? However, in the table it says 0.5V @ 4mA. I would like to know Vce(sat) with collector current in the 10-100mA range.

Comment: It's a typo it's actually milli volts. Bad on Fairchild.

Comment: I thought it was millivolts too, but then it would be 63mV @ 4mA, much lower than the stated maximum of 500mV.